# How to get word (String) only?

Tags: java, string

I am creating a chat application that will filter bad word for example, ass. So, if use type "your face look like ass", the result will be "your face look like ". the code is

```
String msg = e.getMessages();

if(msg.contains("ass"))
{
    String aaa = msg.replace("ass", "");
    //my code here to show msg
}
```

So, if user type a word that contains ass, for example glass, my code will remove the ass and become gl only. So, I want to know how to detect word by word and remove bad words in my list?

Comment: It's inhuman to replace someone's ass with nothing.

Comment: -.- answer the question

Comment: clbuttic problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem. And also I hope this is only an exercise, since there are many ways to bypass a filter.

Comment: I have a solution but it only applies to spherical asses in a vaccum

Comment: lolololololololololololol -.- ass is just a example

Comment: @Jeremy: *"-.- answer the question"* FWIW, that comes across rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace entire words only, you can use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which takes a regular expression instead of a normal string, and *word boundaries* (`\\b`) like this:

```
String aaa = msg.replaceAll("\\bass\\b", "");
```

You can read more on word boundaries in [this excellent tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: it is a regular expression

Comment: it work!!! Thanks. I hope I will not have anyone say ass word now in my chat room

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, it is very powerful. for example, if you just want "ass" as a word you can use `"/^ass$/"`, so you can write it:

```
String aaa = msg.replaceAll("/^ass$/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String msg = e.getMessages();
String[] msgParts = e.getMessages().split(" ");
StringBuilder filteredMessage = new StringBuilder();
for (String msgPart : mstParts){
  if (!msgPart.trim().toLower().equals("[string to be filtered]")){
       filteredMessage.append(msgPart).append(" ");
  }
}
msg = filteredMessage.toString();
// further code continues
```